# How much storage is varnish using?

Tags: storage, varnish

I'm using a 1 GB file storage in my varnish instance, is there a command or anything to get the current usage of that gigabyte?

Answer (score 3):

You can if you've setup the admin listener.

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a 127.0.0.1:8080 \
       -T 127.0.0.1:6082 \
       -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
       -s malloc,256MB"
```

It's the -T 127.0.0.1:6082 line above. I recommend binding it to localhost as it's admin interface. If you want to remote query it you should follow the docs and setup a secret.

```
varnishadm -T localhost:6082 stats
```

The above command run from the server should kick out all sort of interesting stats. I'm using in memory so I see SHM stats. I'm not sure what it looks like for disk.

Answer (score 1):

Use `varnishadm` for command line stats. Or if you want something more pretty and digestible, install `Munin` and grab the Varnish plug-in from [Munin Exchange](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/).